Angular App on GAE with custom domain returns 404 for static files
I have an Angular app.  I have deployed it to GAE.  It works on the default GAE generated URL https://<service>-dot-<app>.oa.r.appspot.com/.  My static Angular app is rendering and the app works 100%.
I have linked a custom domain, hosted with GoDaddy.  DNS is set up with details provided by GAE, and active.  Certificates are managed through Google.
When I visit my custom domain, let's call it 'custom.ai', the index.html is rendered. BUT, all static *.css and *.js files that Angular generates, give a 404 error in the console.  SO I can see my background color for my app, but no content as the *.js and *.css files are not found. Even when trying to view https://custom.ai/assets/images/image.png I also get a not found error:  The requested URL /assets/images/rospen-logo.png was not found on this server.
I have played around with the app.yaml, dispatch.yaml, IAM permissions, DNS settings but I just cannot seem to fix this issue.  If anyone can give any guidance it would be greatly appreciated.  I do not know where to look to fix this issue.
For reference, here is my app.yaml file:
runtime: python312
service: angular

default_expiration: "60s"

handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: dist/assets

- url: /(.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico))
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico))
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
  secure: always



When you use custom domain, requests are routed to default service and version. Does your default service/version has the files?

Yes, I actually figured out what the problem was.  I will update my answer shortly.
Thanks for the assistance
